# How to build this android app (Bluetooth technology)

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am a little confused on how to build this android app. Here's how it should work. I have a list of paired bluetooth devices. Lets say paired devices are: 
1. A bluetooth head set. 
2. A mobile phone.
And my app should automatically connect only to my headset when ever it comes in range.

Thats the basic functionality. I have been doing some research on bluetooth technology and its implementation. I came across the bluetooth chat application, when I started using the application I realized that both phones should have the app on it in order to connect and exchange messages. I tried connecting to my headset but it doesnt connect. And also when I removed the bluetooth chat app from one of my device and tried to connect it from a device which had bluetooth chat app, the devices couldnt connect.

If you have already worked on bluetooth this might look very simple. But how can I connect to a bluetooth device from my app when ever its in range even if the other device doesnt have my app.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be a 2 sections answer:

-To connect to a Bluetooth Headset, check my answer on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24468341/2040750)

-To Always connect to that device, you can save device address to memory then create a service with BroadCastReciever that listens for Bluetooth Connectivity. and check which device gets connected and compare it address to the one save in memory once its finds it connected call ibth.connect(device). ibth is inside the above link.