# Enable the HandsFree profile Android Bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, phone-call

I am able to enable and connect my Android device through A2DP profile 
But I want to enable the HandsFree profile of Bluetooth of Android so  that I can attend calls through my Bluetooth HeadSet.

I am using **IBluetoothHeadset.aidl** for this purpose.
I have followed the under below link but no luck.

[Programmtically connect to bluetooth headset from android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468010/programmtically-connect-to-bluetooth-headset-from-android-app)

The profile is not shown enabled in Default Bluetooth menu of the Bluetooth HeadSet.

Where am I going wrong , Help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to enable your handsfree profile bydefault .The only thing you can do i.e just control the functionality which is ACL through which you can transfer the call over bluetooth or not.

Hope this is helpful to you.
Thanx.