# How to activate Bluetooth hands free during call in android

Tags: android

is there a way to activate BT hands free during a call the same way we can activate speaker with audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true) ?

Thanks

Comment: check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468010/programmtically-connect-to-bluetooth-headset-from-android-app?lq=1). Search well before posting questions and ask programming question not solutions.

Comment: i think you have misunderstood my question, perhaps my english isn't good enough. i don't want to pair the headset, i assume it's already the case. When the user answer the phone and that he is getting the sound in his phone, i want to be able to toggle this to BT output.