# Is it possible to Scan and Connect to the Classic Bluetooth Devices In React native or Kotlin for Android? if yes then How?

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, bluetooth

Is it possible to Scan and Connect to the Classic Bluetooth Devices In React native or Kotlin for Android? if yes then How?

I tried installing with React native Libraries but they are not providing Scanning Functionality to Scan for Classic Bluetooth. I am getting a lot information regarding the BLE Device but there isn't info regarding Classic Bluetooth.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically connect to bluetooth headset from android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468010/programmatically-connect-to-bluetooth-headset-from-android-app)

Comment: Nope, it Connects Headsets which are the BLE Devices. I Need a Solution to Connect Classic Bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

Bluetooth Classic is often referred to by the name Bluetooth Serial. The package [react-native-bluetooth-serial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bluetooth-serial) seems to be a choice for you.

Regarding Bluetooth Classic using Kotlin you could start by following the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth/setup).

Comment: Thank You So much For Your Valuable Response.